# I want to update the one column in database on click the vote button

Tags: php, mysqli

I started writing code for a basic voting system. But I got this error message.

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, bool given
>   in E:\My-WORLD\xampp\htdocs\php-tut\voting\vote.des.php on line 6

```
<?php
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","voting") || die("not 
 connected");
echo "connected";

if(isset($_POST['ele'])){

   global $con;

   $vote_ele = "update votes set ele = ele + 1";
   $run = mysqli_query($con,$vote_ele);

   if($run){
      echo "voted to electronics";
   }
   else{
      echo mysqli_error($run);
   }

  }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Neither `||` or `or` should be ever written in connection to any mysqli function.**

[How to **properly** connect with mysqli](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect):

```
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'voting';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
try {
    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    mysqli_set_charset($con, $charset);
} catch (\mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
     throw new \mysqli_sql_exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
}
```

Given this script is not the only one uses a mysql connection, store this code in a separate file named `mysqli.php` and then include it in other files. Therefore your current code will become

```
<?php
include 'mysqli.php';
if(isset($_POST['ele']))
{
   $vote_ele = "update votes set ele = ele + 1";
   $run = mysqli_query($con,$vote_ele);
   echo "voted to electronics";
}
```

See - it is concise, tidy and reusable.

Answer (score -2):

When you use `$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","voting") || die("not 
 connected");` you are assigning a `bool` to `$con` variable. So it is not `mysqli` anymore.

Also, When you use `global $con` you are overriding `$con` value, So it is not `mysqli` which you assigned in the pervious line anymore.

try this:

```php
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "voting");

        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
            die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());

        echo "connected";

        if (isset($_POST['ele'])) {

            // This will override $con value!!
            // global $con;

            $vote_ele = "update votes set ele = ele + 1";
            $run = mysqli_query($con, $vote_ele);

            if ($run) {
                echo "voted to electronics";
            }
            else {
                echo mysqli_error($run);
            }

        }
```

Comment: your second statement is wrong. global $con is pointless but harmless

Comment: also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318368/mysqli-or-die-does-it-have-to-die

Comment: That's not my statement. Consider that I commented. About die(), that's post owner statement, not mine. I just updated the owners' code.

Comment: "When you use global $con you are overriding $con value" is the second statement you made in your answer.

Comment: Man! I'm just trying to say what is happening! That's not mine again! I commented that in my sample.

Comment: Yes. and you are wrong on this account. Please pay some heed to my words before commenting back. Thank you.